# Problems with Twitter Bootstrap 3.1.x, box-sizing property and Revolution Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a theme for PyroCMS based on Twitter Bootstrap 3.1.x. I'm using also Revolution Slider in the theme. For some reason the property `box-sizing: border-box;` is causing a grey border as image show:

[image]

The border dissapear after few seconds. I applied this code:

```
.noborderbox *, .noborderbox *:before, .noborderbox *:after {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

To the DIV but this doesn't work. How I can fix this problem on my site? You can test [here](http://www.alomicuba.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border-box value makes the final rendered box the declared width, and any border and padding cut inside the box.

So you should use `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: This is not the problem, I changed as you suggested and problem remains